# what package version is installed if I write spack install <package>@master?

Tags: spack

I want to install the latest version of a package using spack.
In the spack manual of the corresponding package, there is the heading Versions: master,...

To which version of the package does master refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will refer to the git master branch tip commit at the moment that you are invoking spack.

This however it is not a good idea since this means that the commit (version) can change at anytime and many project do not ensure that the state in the master branch to be stable.

I recommend you to simply use the preferred version of a package which is chosen by default when you type `spack install <package>`